# How to list files which are greater than particular date in tFileList Component in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I am new to Talend. I am current processing all files in a folder and store into the database.
tFileList -> tFileUnArchive -> tFileInputXML -> tMap-> tDBOutput.
But from next run. I want to retrieve all the latest files in the folder which have greater last modified date than the file stored in database. Once I have the latest files then I want to process each of them and store them into database. Could some one help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tFileProperties that you can place right after the tFileList. You have a field name "mtime" which is the creation date of the file (unix timestamp, you'll have to convert it). Then you'll be able to compare this date with the date you have in your database.